# Why androidx.material3 libraries have totally different components?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

If I use material3 with alpha version "1.2.0-alpha07", I can't use component "RichToolTipBox", it's absent there.
But if I use material3 without mentioning version (it will be used from compose-bom), I have RichToolTipBox, but I won't have there a lot of other components I already implemented. Can you explain how it works? Why I can't find any mentions of removing RichToolTipBox from library ....

Comment: `RichTooltipBox` (note the different captialization compared to your post) was mentioned even in the latest [Compose Material3 1.2.0-alpha07 release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3#1.2.0-alpha07), so it definitely does exist.